# Error al hacer una peticion http put() con angular hacia spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Soy nuevo en spring boot y angular y estoy tratando de actualizar un dato pero el problema está en el frontend con el angular porque ya hice la peticion con Postman y funciona correctamente pero cuando hago la solicitud con el angular no funciona. en angular estaba tratando de quemar los datos y enviarlos pero tampoco funcionó para mí.
"Tengo más métodos que funcionan desde el angular pero los elimino porque no es necesario mostrarlos"

---

back end

---

Esto es @RestController

```
@PutMapping(value = "update/{cantidad}/{idProductos}")
    private void agregarCantidad(@PathVariable("cantidad") int cantidad, @PathVariable Long idProductos){
        try {
            
             productosService.updateCantidad(cantidad,idProductos);
        }catch(Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
```

la interface

```
public interface ProductosRepository extends JpaRepository<Productos, Long>{

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Productos p set p.cantidad = ?1 where p.idProductos = ?2")
    void updateCantidad(Integer entrada,Long id) throws SQLException;
}
```

the  @Service

```
    @Override
    public void updateCantidad(Integer entrada,Long idProductos) {
        List<Productos> productos = productosRepository.findAll();
        Integer resultado;
        try {
            for (Productos pro : productos) {
                if (entrada > 0) {
                    resultado = entrada + pro.getCantidad();
                    productosRepository.updateCantidad(resultado,idProductos);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("la cantidad no es valida");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

2. Front end

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductosService {

  private API_SERVER = "http://localhost:8881/producto/";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  public addCantidad(cantidad:any,id:any): Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.put(this.API_SERVER+"update/",cantidad+"/"+id);
  }
  
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductosService } from '../services/productos/productos.service';
import { MarcaService } from '../services/marca/marca.service';
import { CategoriasService } from '../services/categorias/categorias.service';
import { ValueTransformer } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productos-listar [disableControl]',
  templateUrl: './productos-listar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productos-listar.component.css']
})
export class ProductosListarComponent implements OnInit {


  productos: any;
  productosEditForm1!:FormGroup;


 

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public productosService: ProductosService,
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    
    
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.productosEditForm1= this.fb.group({
      idProductos: [''],
      nombre:  [''],
      cantidad: [''],
      precio: [''], 
    })

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.name = params['name'];
      
    });

    
  }

  tetsEnviar(){
    let id = 1;
    let cantidad = 5;
    this.productosService.addProductos(cantidad,id).subscribe(resp =>{
      console.log(resp)
    })
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
<div class="form-row">
                
</div>
<button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" (click)=" tetsEnviar()" >Agregar</button>
</form>
```

la peticion con Postman es correcta y hace la actualización de la base de datos

```
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.907[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m PUT "/producto/update/5/1", parameters={}
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.910[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to com.millisecondsoftware.ventas.rest.ProductosRest#agregarCantidad(int, Long)
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.987[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m select productos0_.idProductos as idproduc1_4_, productos0_.cantidad as cantidad2_4_, productos0_.categoria_idcategoria as categori6_4_, productos0_.fechaVencimiento as fechaven3_4_, productos0_.marca_idmarca as marca_id7_4_, productos0_.nombre as nombre4_4_, productos0_.operador_idoperador as operador8_4_, productos0_.precio as precio5_4_ from productos productos0_
Hibernate: select productos0_.idProductos as idproduc1_4_, productos0_.cantidad as cantidad2_4_, productos0_.categoria_idcategoria as categori6_4_, productos0_.fechaVencimiento as fechaven3_4_, productos0_.marca_idmarca as marca_id7_4_, productos0_.nombre as nombre4_4_, productos0_.operador_idoperador as operador8_4_, productos0_.precio as precio5_4_ from productos productos0_
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.990[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m select categorias0_.idcategoria as idcatego1_1_0_, categorias0_.nombre as nombre2_1_0_ from categoria categorias0_ where categorias0_.idcategoria=?
Hibernate: select categorias0_.idcategoria as idcatego1_1_0_, categorias0_.nombre as nombre2_1_0_ from categoria categorias0_ where categorias0_.idcategoria=?
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.992[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m select marca0_.idmarca as idmarca1_2_0_, marca0_.nombre as nombre2_2_0_ from marca marca0_ where marca0_.idmarca=?
Hibernate: select marca0_.idmarca as idmarca1_2_0_, marca0_.nombre as nombre2_2_0_ from marca marca0_ where marca0_.idmarca=?
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:12.994[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m select operador0_.idoperador as idoperad1_3_0_, operador0_.cargo as cargo2_3_0_, operador0_.usuario_idusuario as usuario_3_3_0_, usuario1_.idusuario as idusuari1_6_1_, usuario1_.apellido as apellido2_6_1_, usuario1_.correo as correo3_6_1_, usuario1_.direccion as direccio4_6_1_, usuario1_.fechaNacimiento as fechanac5_6_1_, usuario1_.nombre as nombre6_6_1_, usuario1_.rol_idrol as rol_idro7_6_1_, rol2_.idrol as idrol1_5_2_, rol2_.nombre as nombre2_5_2_ from operador operador0_ left outer join usuario usuario1_ on operador0_.usuario_idusuario=usuario1_.idusuario left outer join rol rol2_ on usuario1_.rol_idrol=rol2_.idrol where operador0_.idoperador=?
Hibernate: select operador0_.idoperador as idoperad1_3_0_, operador0_.cargo as cargo2_3_0_, operador0_.usuario_idusuario as usuario_3_3_0_, usuario1_.idusuario as idusuari1_6_1_, usuario1_.apellido as apellido2_6_1_, usuario1_.correo as correo3_6_1_, usuario1_.direccion as direccio4_6_1_, usuario1_.fechaNacimiento as fechanac5_6_1_, usuario1_.nombre as nombre6_6_1_, usuario1_.rol_idrol as rol_idro7_6_1_, rol2_.idrol as idrol1_5_2_, rol2_.nombre as nombre2_5_2_ from operador operador0_ left outer join usuario usuario1_ on operador0_.usuario_idusuario=usuario1_.idusuario left outer join rol rol2_ on usuario1_.rol_idrol=rol2_.idrol where operador0_.idoperador=?
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:13.107[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m update productos set cantidad=? where idProductos=?
Hibernate: update productos set cantidad=? where idProductos=?
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:13.128[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36mm.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:13.128[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36mm.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Nothing to write: null body
[2m2021-01-16 14:33:13.129[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
```

Peticion con angular y este es el error

```
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.480[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m OPTIONS "/producto/update/", parameters={}
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.481[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.483[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-6][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.488[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m PUT "/producto/update/", parameters={}
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.490[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.496[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resource not found
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.497[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.497[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m "ERROR" dispatch for PUT "/error", parameters={}
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.498[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.499[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.500[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Writing [{timestamp=Sat Jan 16 14:35:37 EST 2021, status=404, error=Not Found, message=, path=/producto/updat (truncated)...]
[2m2021-01-16 14:35:37.501[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m16976[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8881-exec-7][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

XHR console

```
General:
Request URL: http://localhost:8881/producto/update/
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8881
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Payload
5/1
```

Comment: El error está aquí: `(this.API_SERVER+"update/",cantidad+"/"+id);` en lugar una coma `,` debe ir un signo más `+`

Comment: @Lobos ya habia probado hacer eso pero resivo un error `An argument for body was not provided`

Comment: Se debe a que `put()` requiere dos parámetros: la url  y el body. En el parámetro body puedes pasarle un `null`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda aceptar tu respuesta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione añadiendo + y ,{} al final

```
return this.httpClient.put(this.API_SERVER+"update/"+cantidad+"/"+id,{});
```